# can a video card 'silently' fail?

Tags: graphics-card, troubleshooting

I've been running a [asus gforce 8800 gts 320mb](http://www.techspot.com/review/47-asus-geforce-8800gts/) on my desktop, and apparently there was a sudden failure. I'm getting no output from it, but the system seems to have booted up - since i can hear sound from it. Monitor seems fine, but i have no other DVI-D devices to test if its a DVI issue, but VGA input into the monitor works fine.

So, could a video card fail in such a way that it might pass POST tests, and the system could still boot up?

EDIT: should it be relevant, the system runs windows XP professional.Ping and RDP are disabled.  I'll also be trying the card on another system later

**Tested**: different computer using VGA on monitor

Switching DVI ports on the same card

Switching DVI cables - apparently works for a while then goes down again

**Not possible to test right at the moment**

Trying a different card on the system (but that would solve the problem if it *is* a mysterious card failure)

**SUSPECTS**

Overheating - the card worked when switched on after it was shut down.

Cable - ruled out

Connection - switched cables, both cables were secured during testing

Comment: It is certainly possible if a bit unlikely.  I would check the DVI pins on the card and look at getting another DVI cable to test with.  Can you ping the PC?

Comment: Yes, happened to me to over reboot.

Comment: PC seems to be up, i can hear sound from it. I get no output from both DVI ports on the card. I'll be testing another cable/monitor later when i have time. I believe ping is disabled by default on windows XP so thats not an option. Dropbox detected it connecting on the last, displayless possible boot however

Comment: rdp into the system?

Comment: RDP seems disabled. I could have sworn it was enabled. Edited my question to reflect that

Comment: Just to help you troubleshoot: You might consider booting some rescue disk (Linux or Windows PE), which activates SSH or RDP automatically. Then you could test if the computer boots up normally, apart from the display.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is yes. The final output stage of the card could fail. POST cannot test this.

Comment: I ended up replacing the card. Taking apart the card seems to indicate the heat sink compound was dried up and crusty, and the consistency of dried toothpaste. Considering that it DID boot, to some extent, this seems the logical conclusion